# How to write to the cell below level 0 of a multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a df with a MultiIndex like so

```py
nums = np.arange(5)
key = ['kfc'] * 5

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([key,nums])

df = pd.DataFrame({'rent': np.arange(10,60,10)})

df.set_index(mi)
```

```
        rent
kfc 0   10
    1   20
    2   30
    3   40
    4   50
```

How can I write to the cell below `kfc`, I want to add meta info e.g. The address or the monthly rent

```
            rent
kfc    0    10
NYC    1    20
       2    30
       3    40
       4    50
```

Comment: it's not "below", it's IN level `0`, and according to your output `kfc` would have 1 key, and `NYC` - 4 keys on level `0`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've updated the question with what I initially have, and what I want the output to be. I see what you're saying tho, I need to change the MultiIndex keys

Comment: @meghidey you seem to believe that the space below "kfc" is empty, which is incorrect. It actually contains "kfc" but pandas hides identical sequential values in a MultiIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your expected output you would need to recreate the `df` MultiIndex:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(['kfc'] + ['NYC'] * 4, df.index.levels[1]))
print(df)
```

---

```
       rent
kfc 0    10
NYC 1    20
    2    30
    3    40
    4    50
```